# Use bash to create array from files using ? wildcard?

Tags: bash, array

I need to iterate through files in a directory that match a specific pattern using an array. For example:

```
./dirx/file1b_t1.tif
./dirx/file2b_z_t2_tif
./dirx/file3b_t3.tif
./dirx/file4b_x_t4.tif
```

I'm trying to build an array that lists the 1st and 3rd file above. I know 'ls' is not an appropriate way to build an array, but I've tried 'find' and it does not work with the '?' wildcard. Basically I'm trying to duplicate:

```
ls ./dirx/*b_??.tif
```

but then pipe the list into an array.

Answer (score 3):

Just store the expansion of the glob expression directly:

```
array=(./dirx/*b_??.tif)
```

BTW, the `./` is generally redundant; you could just use `array=(dirx/*b_??.tif)` and get valid paths to the same files.

[This seems like it should be a duplicate of an earlier question, but I can't find a good match for it. Anyone else?]

Comment: its only redundant until you dont recognize that the path is wrong (if it was) . I was mentoring a beginner and suggested he always use ./ so that he learns that it means the files is right here in this directory... If it doesnt have the `./` we sometimes don't notice and forget to check the path when debugging things.  So depends on skill level, but good for the mention..